# React createElement children syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple react component that passes an array of objects with one value that is another React component as follows (and yes I know this could be converted to a functional component but that does not matter for this question):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import GeneralPage from 'AdminApp/client/components/conference/GeneralPage'
import TopicPage from 'AdminApp/client/components/conference/TopicPage'
import NewPage from 'common/client/components/wizard/NewPage'

export default class TestWizard extends Component {

  render() {
    let steps=[
      {name: "One", node: GeneralPage},
      {name: "Two", node: TopicPage},
      {name: "Three", node: TopicPage},
    ]
    return (
      <NewPage steps={steps} name='Conference'/>
    )
  }
}
```

This in another component that happens to be wrapped in a seperate HOC, but the HOC is not relevant to this question, I am creating the components passed in from above - React.createElement(step.node) in the code below:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import {NewWrapper} from 'common/client/components/wizard/NewWrapper'
import WizardButtons from 'common/client/components/wizard/WizardButtons'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import CONSTANTS from 'common/client/constants'

let NewPage = NewWrapper(class extends Component {
  render() {
    const {steps, page, name} = this.props
    let stepCount = steps.length
    let stepName = steps[page - 1].name
    let submit = steps[page - 1].submit
    let stepPreText = `${name}`
    let stepPostText = ` Wizard - ${stepName} (Step ${page} of ${stepCount})`
    //TODO: select with steps - if ID and/or valid?
    let title = <div><h2 style={{textAlign: 'center', color: CONSTANTS.EP_COLOR_BROWN}}>
      {name && stepPreText}{stepCount > 1 && stepPostText}
    </h2></div>

    return (
      <div>
        {page}
        {steps.map((step, index) =>
          <div key={index}>
            {page === (index + 1) ? title : null}
            {/* ***HERE IS WHERE THE NODES ARE ADDED *** */}
            {page === (index + 1) ? React.createElement(step.node) : null}
          </div>
        )}
        {/* ***I NEED TO ADD THIS AS A CHILD TO THE createElement *** */}
        <WizardButtons submit={submit} {...this.props}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
})

export default NewPage
```

What I need to do and can't seem to figure out how is to add the `<Wizard Buttons/>` element above as a child of the createElement. I tired things like `React.createElement(step.node, null, <WizardButtons submit={submit} {...this.props}/>)` and creating a variable with the wizard buttons element and passing that variable as the 3rd parameter to the creatElement, but nothing seems to work. Any ideas on how best to do this?

TIA!

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Can you show a simple example of how you would like the DOM to look given a particular input? I don't think you should be using `React.createElement` in JSX.

Comment: There are no errors and the applicable vdom should looks something like `<GeneralPage><WizardButtons {with props}/></GeneralPage>`

Answer (score 2):

Try changing

```
let steps=[
  {name: "One", node: GeneralPage},
  {name: "Two", node: TopicPage},
  {name: "Three", node: TopicPage},
]
```

to

```
let steps=[
      {name: "One", node: <GeneralPage />},
      {name: "Two", node: <TopicPage />},
      {name: "Three", node: <TopicPage />},
    ]
```

and this

```
 {page === (index + 1) ? React.createElement(step.node) : null}
```

to

```
 {page === (index + 1) ? step.node : null}
```

**Edited to add the button to step.node**

To add the wizard button to step.node ... you could do something

```
let wizardButton = <WizardButtons submit={submit} {...this.props}/>
React.cloneElement(step.node, {wizardButton : wizardButton});
```

You'll get it as a prop in your step.node

Comment: That will work in general, but does not solve the issue of getting the needed child. It id basically is another way to give me exactly what I have now.

Comment: So you want to add WizardButtons to the element? pass it as a prop.

Comment: The props thing works, but then all the step components have to be modified to render it, which is why I was trying to make it a child instead of a prop. I can work with that, but not accepting the answer (I did flag it as useful though) hoping someone will chime in with a child solution that works too.

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks to @QoP pointing me in the right direction, I was able to finally figure this out...

```
let wizardButtons = <WizardButtons submit={submit} {...this.props}/>
{page === (index + 1) ? React.createElement(step.node, {...this.props}, wizardButtons) : null
```

That passes the buttons as a child to each step node and this.props.children in the step nodes displays them.